# Vite manifest not found at: /app/public/build/manifest.json (View: /app/resources/views/app.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, vite

Can someone tell me why i get this error after deployng the app pn heroku?

Vite manifest not found at: /app/public/build/manifest.json (View: /app/resources/views/app.blade.php)